# Drag instead of scroll inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to let the user drag the image rather than have to scroll to the right (see [here](http://blameless.eu))

It works how I want it to using:

```
$("#timeline").draggable({
axis: "x",
});
```

The problem is when the user reaches the end of the image they can still keep dragging rather than it stopping.

Is there a more effective way so that when it reaches the end it stops just like when the user scrolls to the end?

Comment: Use the [drag event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a callback to `draggable` that checks the width of the page compared to the width of the image and where it is on the page.

Something like:

```
$("#timeline").draggable({
   axis: "x",
   drag: function(event, ui){
      var position = ui.position;
      var offset = ui.offset;
      //code returns false if your check does not go through
      //your code to check if the user can drag anymore
   }
});
```